# Convert a Set<Integer> to a primitive array

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, set

I am using the following code to convert a Set to int[]

```
Set<Integer> common = new HashSet<Integer>();
int[] myArray = (int[]) common.toArray();
```

the I got the following error:

```
 error: incompatible types: Object[] cannot be converted to int[]
```

What would be the most clean way to do the conversion without adding element one by one using a for loop? Thanks!

Comment: Finally a well-formatted question with proper grammar on StackOverflow

Answer (score 9):

You usually do this:

```
Set<Integer> common = new HashSet<Integer>();
int[] myArray = common.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

Comment: dude, i want to learn about `::` operator where do i learn it form ?

Comment: @TilakMadichetti This is called a "method reference". See e.g. here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: so `intValue` is a method in the Integer class ?

Comment: Correct: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue--

Answer (score 7):

```
Set<Integer> common = new HashSet<>();
int[] values = Ints.toArray(common);
```

Comment: `Integer[] != int[]`

Comment: Changed now to use the Guava's helper library.

Answer (score 2):

> You cannot explicitly cast something into an array.

Do this:

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[common.size()];
Iterator<Integer> iterator = common.iterator(); 
int i = 0;
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    arr[i++] = iterator.next();
}
```

Comment: @tom why would the code not compile ?

Comment: @tom  now would it work ?

Comment: @Tom Please edit my answer

Comment: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321)